# Undefined method `options_for_select'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm having some trouble with where to define helper methods that are used by more than one controller.

I extracted this method into its own module:

```
module ColumnMapHelper
  def drop_down_upload_file_types
    options = [["Use the RoyaltyZone Sales Upload Template", "RZ"], ["Use my own data file (Quickbooks, iTunes, etc)", "Create New"]]
    ...
    select_tag "file_upload_type", options_for_select(options, default), :id=>"upload_file_type_selection"
  end
end
```

I included it in the controller and exposed it as a helper method:

```
class SalesDataController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [:download]

  include ColumnMapHelper
  helper_method :drop_down_upload_file_types
```

When it was defined in my controller's helper (app/helpers/sales_data_helper.rb) it was fine, but now I'm getting this error when my helper method is invoked in the view:

```
undefined method `options_for_select' for #<SalesDataController:0x109bbbd18>
```

Is there some module I would need to include? What's the best way to share helpers like this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're including it in your controller?

Comment: I had read somewhere to put shared helper methods in ApplicationController.

Answer (score 1):

If your only using the helper in your views then you don't need to do anything as everything in app/helpers is included by default.

You want to use helper_method in your controller when you have methods like current_user that you want to share with the view.

Answer (score 0):

The `options_for_select` is a view method and it's not available in the controller. However, there is no reason to use it in the controller.

If you save the `ColumnMapHelper` file in the `/app/helpers` folder, the `drop_down_upload_file_types` will automatically be available to all your views (as long as your app includes all the helpers by default).

Comment: Is it accessible globally? No namespace prefix?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are in the view.